Is there an aggregate array function in Matlab? And is it possible to reference different index in such array function?
Is there an aggregate array function in Matlab similar to reduce in Google Sheet or foldr in Racket?
For example, the other day, I was hoping to extract/exclude a row representing every third week of the month,



isnumeric() => true
isnumeric() => true




202211
data_to_be_aggregated_type_1


202211
data_to_be_aggregated_type_1


202211
data_to_be_aggregated_type_2


202211
data_to_be_aggregated_type_1


202211
data_to_be_aggregated_type_1


202212
data_to_be_aggregated_type_1


202212
data_to_be_aggregated_type_1


202212
data_to_be_aggregated_type_2


202212
data_to_be_aggregated_type_1



I ended up copying the data to Google Sheet, where the data can be processed with one (local) function, and only then copied to Matlab
As well, in the above example, it is necessary(?) to be able to reference a different index based on a preset offset from the current index. In order to tell whether a row represents the 3rd week of a month, one way is to, for example, check whether month digits are different from 3 rows before but the same as 2 rows before. Google Sheet allows for this via offset. (Google Sheet reduce also only accepts 1D array as argument, further increasing the need for offset.)
So..  Is there an Matlab equivalent for reduce or foldr and the corresponding tools such as offset?

I am not clear as to what you want to accomplish. Could you include example input and output data?

@CrisLuengo From what I understand, all of the rows labeled 202211 in column 1 are assigned to be aggregated type 1, except for the third instance, which is assigned to type 2. Similarly for rows labeled 202212, and so on.

You could use the diff (difference vs the previous sample) of the months array to look for when it changes, i.e. where the diff is non-zero. Then you find these indices and add two to them to offset by 2 weeks.
idx = find([true; diff(m)~=0])+2;

If you want to generate the 2nd column in your example then the full code would look something like
% Example input data
m = [202211, 202211, 202211, 202211, 202211, 202212, 202212, 202212, 202212];

% Find indices where month changes, offset by two weeks.
% First sample is always true as we want to count the first week in the input
% and "diff" returns an array one element shorter than the input
dm = find([true; diff(m(:))~=0])+2;

% Create an output with type "1" as the default and "2" for the 3rd-week indices
dm( dm > numel(m) ) = []; % Handle edge case where the offset exceeded the array size
aggType = ones(size(m));
aggType(dm) = 2;


Prompted by @beaker's comment, here's a way to do it with a simple loop which keeps track of how many consecutive equal values there are for each sample, and then finds the corresponding indices by checking if the count equals 3. This is more robust to inputs which might not have 3 consecutive values the same in each batch.
% Trickier input with <3 samples for some values, inc. at start
m = [202210, 202210, 202211, 202211, 202211, 202211, 202211, 202212, 202212, 202212, 202212, 202301, 202301, 202302, 202302, 202302];

N = ones(size(m));
for ii = 2:numel(N)
    if m(ii) == m(ii-1)
        N(ii) = N(ii-1) + 1; % another consecutive equal value
    else
        N(ii) = 1;           % reset the counter, value changed
    end
end

aggType = ones(size(m));
aggType( N==3 ) = 2; % N==3 are the desired samples


This assumes that there actually is a 3rd instance for each timestamp, which may or may not be true. Honestly, I'd rather iterate through the list.

@beaker given that OP's context is weeks in a month, there always will be. I've handled the edge-case already that the list ends too soon, the only other edge case is that the list starts mid-month which could also be handled. I've expanded my example to show how it could be done in a loop for more robustness though

Agreed. If only Mathworks had given us run-length encoding and cumulative run-length.

@beaker it's not particularly nice looking or efficient, but you can get the run-lengths with arrayfun(@(x)1+x-find([NaN,m(1:x)]~=m(x),1,'last'),1:numel(m)); to replace that loop. Albeit arrayfun is basically a loop anyway...
